# How can I use the .findIndex() method be used in spliced arrays in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, out-of-memory

I've been working throught the introduction to JavaScript course on Codecademy
https://www.codecademy.com/courses/introduction-to-javascript/lessons/javascript-iterators/exercises/find-index and thought I would try to extend one of their ideas to search for all strings within an array that start with the string 's'.

I define an example array called animals and populate it with some strings. First I use the `.findIndex()` method to find the first animal name beginning with `'s'` and save its value to a variable named `sIndex`. Then I try to splice the animals array from `sIndex + 1`, apply `findIndex()` and then update `sIndex` with the value returned.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
const animals = ['hippo', 'tiger', 'lion', 'seal', 'cheetah', 'monkey', 'salamander', 'elephant'];

//Create a function that finds all animals in the array animals starting with the letter s.

let sNameAnimals = [];
let sIndex = animals.findIndex(animal => animal[0] === 's');
let numOfAnimals = animals.length

while (sIndex !== -1){
    // Push the current found animal onto the array sNameAnimals
    sNameAnimals.push(animals[sIndex])
    // Find the next animal that starts with s in the animals array.
    animalSlice = animals.slice(sIndex+1);
    sIndex = animalSlice.findIndex(animal => animal[0] === 's');

}
```

However, when I run this in the console through node.js,  I get the following error message:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[16999:0x103240000]   104105 ms: Mark-sweep 577.2 (588.5) -> 577.2 (581.5) MB, 1429.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.913, current mu = 0.000) last resort GC in old space requested
[16999:0x103240000]   105504 ms: Mark-sweep 577.2 (581.5) -> 577.2 (581.5) MB, 1398.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.801, current mu = 0.000) last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x2e143204fb7d]
Security context: 0x0d42a071d969 <JSObject>
    1: /* anonymous */ [0xd427bf849e9] [/Users/cmg18/Documents/Javascript/Iterators/iterators.js:~1] [pc=0x2e14320f0b82](this=0x0d427bf84b19 <Object map = 0xd42f1a82521>,0x0d427bf84b19 <Object map = 0xd42f1a82521>,0x0d427bf84ad9 <JSFunction require (sfi = 0xd42db01b049)>,0x0d427bf84a51 <Module map = 0xd42f1acbc21>,0x0d42db021c49 <String[56]: /Users/cmg18/Doc...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x10003a9d9 node::Abort() [/Users/cmg18/.nvm/versions/node/v11.0.0/bin/node]
 2: 0x10003abe4 node::FatalTryCatch::~FatalTryCatch() [/Users/cmg18/.nvm/versions/node/v11.0.0/bin/node]
 3: 0x10019ed17 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/Users/cmg18/.nvm/versions/node/v11.0.0/bin/node]
 4: 0x10019ecb4 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/Users/cmg18/.nvm/versions/node/v11.0.0/bin/node]
 5: 0x1005a5882 v8::internal::Heap::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*) [/Users/cmg18/.nvm/versions/node/v11.0.0/bin/node]
 6: 0x1005aedd4 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/Users/cmg18/.nvm/versions/node/v11.0.0/bin/node]
 7: 0x10057d3c6 v8::internal::Factory::NewFixedArrayWithFiller(v8::internal::Heap::RootListIndex, int, v8::internal::Object*, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/Users/cmg18/.nvm/versions/node/v11.0.0/bin/node]
 8: 0x1005238c4 v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::ElementsAccessorBase<v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::FastPackedObjectElementsAccessor, v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::ElementsKindTraits<(v8::internal::ElementsKind)2> >::GrowCapacity(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>, unsigned int) [/Users/cmg18/.nvm/versions/node/v11.0.0/bin/node]
 9: 0x1007fec82 v8::internal::Runtime_GrowArrayElements(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/Users/cmg18/.nvm/versions/node/v11.0.0/bin/node]
10: 0x2e143204fb7d
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing that is causing the error? I would have thought my while loop should terminate due to the splicing.

Comment: do you want to fix the code or a better solution?

Comment: I've managed to fix it by copying the animals array, but probably still quite longwinded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically yo have used `slice` (even though you said `splice` in question title).
I would advice you to use the following code, it basically does the same thing, with a little less steps:

```
const animals = ['hippo', 'tiger', 'lion', 'seal', 'cheetah', 'monkey', 'salamander', 'elephant'];
const sNameAnimals = animals.filter(animal => animal[0] === "s");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes you are absolutely correct, I meant to say `slice` - sorry for the confusion. Without realising, I've implemented the filter function from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) (delete or insert into an array) the array instead of using [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) (get subarray).

For this approach you mutate `animals` and get anoter array of the wanted items starting with `s`.

```js
const
    animals = ['hippo', 'tiger', 'lion', 'seal', 'cheetah', 'monkey', 'salamander', 'elephant'],
    sNameAnimals = []
    startsWithS = animal => animal[0] === 's';

let sIndex = animals.findIndex(startsWithS);

while (sIndex !== -1) {
    sNameAnimals.push(...animals.splice(sIndex, 1));
    sIndex = animals.findIndex(startsWithS);
}

console.log(sNameAnimals);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Nina. I did mean to say `slice` in my title and not `splice`.  However, it is always useful to consider other approaches. I'm not quite sure what the `...` before `animals.splice` is doing in the first line of the while loop. Is there somewhere I can look this up in the documentation?

Comment: just look to [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix my own code, but probably still a bit long winded. I have copied the animals array and then reassigned it to the output of `animals.slice(sIndex + 1)` in the loop.

```js
const animals = ['hippo', 'tiger', 'lion', 'seal', 'cheetah', 'monkey', 'salamander', 'elephant'];

let sNameAnimals = [];
let sIndex = animals.findIndex(animal => animal[0] === 's');
let numOfAnimals = animals.length;
// Create a copy of animals
let animalsCopy = animals;

while (sIndex !== -1){
    // Push the current found animal onto the array sNameAnimals
    sNameAnimals.push(animalsCopy[sIndex])
    // Find the next animal that starts with s in the animals array.
    animalsCopy = animalsCopy.slice(sIndex+1);
    //console.log(animalsCopy);

    sIndex = animalsCopy.findIndex(animal => animal[0] === 's');
    //console.log(sIndex);

}
```